# Facebook Pixel API get_stats() doesn't provide match data

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-pixel

I have troubles with getting Pixel stats. I did on Python:

```
pixel = AdsPixel(<PIXEL_ID>)
pixel.get_stats(params={'aggregation': 'event', 'start_time': '2015-12-07'})
```

And I received:

```
<AdsPixelStat> {
"aggregation": "event",
"data": [
 {
"count": 1,
"value": "ViewContent"
 },
{
"count": 1,
"value": "PageView"
}
],
"timestamp": "2015-12-07T08:00:00"
```

But in Ads manager I see that data doesn't match. looks like I don't know how to use properly "start_date", "end_date". I tried many variants but data doesn't much for any period of time.
On screenshot there is an ads manager stats for December 7

[image: ads manager stats for December 7]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Python Facebook-Ads-SDK. I did submit bug report.